# Woocommerce хук после нажатия на кнопку "Добавить в корзину"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

После нажатия на "Добавить в корзину" перед товарами имею сообщение: "товар добавлен в корзину".
Какой хук используется при этом? 
Хочу написать еще свой кастомный текст (функцию) которая бы выводила туда данные.
Именно перед продуктами, там же где и сообщения WooCommerce.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто воспользоваться фильтром `wc_add_to_cart_message`:

```
function mihdan_wc_add_to_cart_message( $message, $product_id ) {
    return 'Ваш текст';
}
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'mihdan_wc_add_to_cart_message', 10, 2 );
```